# use isinstance() cannot check python object class import other module

Tags: python, classname, isinstance

```
class A:
    somemethod
```

`class A` in module `m1`

in module `m2` I want to use `isinstance()` to check object `obj1` is or not class `A`

and `obj1 = A()`

but `isinstance(obj1,A)` is `False`....`type(obj1) == <class, m1.A>`

I can't understand why? help me

Comment: This question needs a cleanup (I'm not 100% on what you're asking), but if I understand correctly, you made an instance of a class `A`, but testing it with `isinstance` says it is not an instance of `A`? I'd suggest providing real code, but a common cause of this problem is if you're working in the interactive interpreter and repeatedly defining `A` and `reload`ing the associated module. When you create an instance, it will be based on the currently loaded definition of `A`, but reloading the module will create a new, unrelated definition of `A`.

Comment: How about `from m1 import A` in the module m2?

Comment: thank you – ShadowRanger – Kota Mori

Answer (score 0):

you need to explicitly import the class you are checking against to
E.g.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...

print(type(td)) --> outputs {type} = <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
if isinstance(td, Tag): --> {NameError}name 'Tag' is not defined

so you need to import Tag
from bs4.element import Tag
```